# Search Firebase database for a value using orderByKey not working DailogFlow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am trying to get all the values ​​of "NOME_DISCIPLINA" by passing "OITAVO_PERIODO".
With that, list JUST all the "NOME_DISCIPLINA".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsE1H.png)

```
  function getGradePeriodoHandler(agent) {
return admin.database().ref("DISCIPLINA").child(agent.parameters.NomePeriodo).orderByKey().once('value').forEach((snapshot) => {
  var value = snapshot.child("NOME_DISCIPLINA").val();
  agent.add(`Materials:` + value);
  });
}
```

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: Hi. I receive "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: In FireBase logs: "TypeError: admin.database(...).ref(...).child(...).orderByKey(...).once(...).forEach is not a function"